# Is there any way to make two jQuery animations run (properly) simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have an event listener that calls two animation actions. Unfortunately their starts are staggered by a small amount (e.g. the first in the function starts first).

Does anyone know a way to properly sync them up?

Here's my code:

```
$("#nav ul li a").hover(
    function(){
        $(lastBlock).children("div").animate({width: "0px"}, { queue:false, duration:400, easing:"swing" });
        $(this).children("div").animate({width: maxWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:400, easing:"swing"});
        lastBlock = this;
    }
);
```

Because the first animation runs slightly before the second, it causes the overall width to become momentarily unequal, which looks a bit funky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a recent disussion about this exact topic on the jQuery dev list. They created a [few test cases](http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/sync-animations/) you might wanna look at. [Specially the Johns test.](http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/sync-animations/johns.html)

[Here's](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/8319a8d4e63a5b65?pli=1) the discussion topic btw.

Comment: By way of a follow up: It's showing a lot of promise, but currently has a couple of problems.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to have a single interval/callback in which all elements are updated.
You can find an example in my post here:

[Can I implement a callback with each animation step in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361275/can-i-implement-a-callback-with-each-animation-step-in-jquery/1846118#1846118)

What you end up is basically:

```
var el1 = $("#element1");
var el2 = $("#element2");

var animation = new AnimationTimeline( {
    easing: "swing"
  , onstep: function( stepValue, animprops )
    {
      // This is called for every animation frame. Set the elements:
      el1.css( { left: ..., top: ... } );
      el2.css( { left: ..., top: ... } );
    }
  });

// And start it.
animation.start();
```