# Can I implement a callback with each animation step in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, effect, timeline

I'd like to implement an animation in my site which:

- needs to update multiple DOM elements.
- each DOM element has it's own animation path (depends on their position)
- and still have an easing effect.

If I call jQuery's animate() function for each element (with queue: false), it will make each element move slightly out of sync with the rest. Makes sense, since there are multiple timers running.

Can I have just one timer event, with a callback for each animation step?
Something like:

```
jQuery.fx.timeline( from, to, easing, function( step, total ) {

      var percentage = step / total;
      // ...update DOM elements based on the percentage of the animation

} );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All timers in JavaScript are based on the native plain old school JavaScript function `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Even jQuery uses this internally.

The trick to synchronize timers, is making sure there is only one `setInterval()` is invoked, so build something ourselves.

An animation can be designed with:

- have 10 steps, each with an interval of 30ms.
- The total animation takes 300ms.
- At each step, the current progress/percentage can be calculated:

  var percentage = ( currentStep / totalSteps );

Now, each time your function is called by `setInterval()`, you can set all DOM elements at once to the correct positions. To find out where an element should be at each animation frame, you use the:

```
var diff       = ( to - from );
var stepValue  = from + diff * percentage;
```

The jQuery easing functions can be called directly, and the final statement becomes:

```
var stepValue  = jQuery.easing[ easingMethod ]( percentage, 0, from, diff );
```

---

I've turned this into a class:

```
/**
 * Animation timeline, with a callback.
 */
function AnimationTimeline( params, onstep )
{
  // Copy values.

  // Required:
  this.from     = params.from || 0;         // e.g. 0%
  this.to       = params.to   || 1;         // e.g. 100%
  this.onstep   = onstep || params.onstep;  // pass the callback.

  // Optional
  this.steps    = params.steps    || 10;
  this.duration = params.duration || 300;
  this.easing   = params.easing   || "linear";

  // Internal
  this._diff  = 0;
  this._step  = 1;
  this._timer = 0;
}

jQuery.extend( AnimationTimeline.prototype, {

  start: function()
  {
    if( this.from == this.to )
      return;

    if( this._timer > 0 )
    {
      self.console && console.error("DOUBLE START!");
      return;
    }

    var myself  = this;    
    this._diff  = ( this.to - this.from );
    this._timer = setInterval( function() { myself.doStep() }, this.duration / this.steps );
  }

, stop: function()
  {
    clearInterval( this._timer );
    this._timer = -1;
    this._queue = [];
  }

, doStep: function()
  {
    // jQuery version of: stepValue = from + diff * percentage;
    var percentage = ( this._step / this.steps );
    var stepValue  = jQuery.easing[ this.easing ]( percentage, 0, this.from, this._diff );

    // Next step
    var props = { animationId: this._timer + 10
                , percentage: percentage
                , from: this.from, to: this.to
                , step: this._step, steps: this.steps
                };
    if( ++this._step > this.steps )
    {
      stepValue = this.to;  // avoid rounding errors.
      this.stop();
    }

    // Callback
    if( this.onstep( stepValue, props ) === false ) {
      this.stop();
    }
  }
});
```

And now you can use:

```
var el1 = $("#element1");
var el2 = $("#element2");

var animation = new AnimationTimeline( {
    easing: "swing"
  , onstep: function( stepValue, animprops )
    {
      // This is called for every animation frame. Set the elements:
      el1.css( { left: ..., top: ... } );
      el2.css( { left: ..., top: ... } );
    }
  });

// And start it.
animation.start();
```

Adding a pause/resume is an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

look at this article: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fun-with-jquerys-animate/

very clear, very easy!

Comment: nice find! much easier than the "best answer".

Comment: That link is dead, but the content is available at https://web.archive.org/web/20200925113411/https://j11y.io/javascript/fun-with-jquerys-animate/

Answer (score 4):

A simple answer to do it. Maybe someone will search it as i did.

We can user the "step" attribute in the animation function.

```
$(obj).animate(
    {
        left: 0
    },
    {
        duration: 50,
        step: function( currentLeft ){
            console.log( "Left: ", currentLeft );
        }
    }
 );
```

So for each step, this will log the current left position

Comment: Ah, it seems jQuery has support for that now. nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

did you check [jquery queue](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/queue)?

You can queue your animations and set a callback on each of them, I think if you play little bit with it you can achieve what you want.

Hope it helps, Sinan.